# Fill a webpage fields automatic

Tags: android, webview

**It's possible that my application send values and fill a webpage fields automatic?**

**`for example : after clicking on a button in my app , the app open a Specified  webpage and fill The Fields with my values - like user & password`**

Edited :

**And It's possible that my application after sending values and fill a webpage fields , Click Submit Button automatic?**

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have called

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Write a javascript function to do what you want and then you can call it like this:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:myfunction('first', 'last')");
```

for example.

Comment: Instead first & last , i should use my user & password?

Comment: Yes, thats just an example.

Comment: so , how can understand that my webpage have How many field? - & how i can find my values fill right field and no another fields?

Comment: You should write that part in javascript - use jquery

Comment: you can send data through the call with json, yes